# What are some in-flight features and are there smoking areas in airports?

Tags: air-travel, airports, regulations, aircraft, united-airlines

I am new at this site so I might not be the best at explaining what question I am asking.

First off, I'll tell you what flight/seats I am on:
I'm flying with united
1. Airbus A320-seat 7C
2. Canadair regional jet 700- seat 18B
3. Bombarder Q400- seat 7B
4. Boeing 737-900-seat 8D

I do have fear of flight so I do like to keep myself busy. A few questions I have are: Is there any wifi (because I know some planes have that), also are cellphones allowed to be used/turned on in a plane? Are you able to use your computer, and last but not least are there plug ins to plug a device in to charge it?

Another part of this post is that I am a smoker. I will be leaving from Seattle airport, having a lay over in San Francisco and then going to Oklahoma. On the way back I have a lay over in Denver. In any of these airports are there smoking areas to go outside or anything, or do I have to go all the way to the entrance and before my flight go threw customs again just to have a smoke?

Comment: You have asked many questions here. Pleas try to focus each post to a single question--but you may make as many posts as you wish.

Comment: For your first question, about WiFi, I think [this post](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21992/how-do-i-find-out-whether-my-flight-has-wifi) will help you. You can update your post to keep only the question about smoking in airports.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully these will help you. Flying is by far the safest way to get around, so you should try to calm yourself and enjoy the experience!

[Airbus A320](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/United_Airlines_Airbus_320_200_After09JUN.php):

- Wifi - yes, above 10,000 ft.
- Power socket - No.

[CRJ 700](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/United_Airlines_Canadair_CRJ700_D.php):

- WiFi - No
- Power socket - No

[Q400](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/United_Airlines_Q400_A.php):

- WiFi - No
- Power socket - No

[737-900](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/United_Airlines_Boeing_737-900_A.php):

- WiFi - No
- Power socket - Yes (but its shared)

For cell phones, according to United's [electronic device policy](http://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/baggage/devices.aspx):

> Travelers may use small, lightweight portable electronic devices (as
>   specified below) in "airplane mode" on United-operated flights.
>   **Cellular service must always be turned off prior to departure.** Flight
>   attendants will announce when devices may be used in flight, with
>   general guidelines as follows:
>
> Within the U.S. (includes U.S. territories), travelers may use
>   permitted devices at all times. Between the U.S. and an international
>   location, travelers may use permitted devices except when departing
>   from or arriving into the international location, unless flight
>   attendants have announced that permitted devices can be used
>   throughout the flight. Outside of the U.S., permitted devices may only
>   be used above 10,000 feet, unless flight attendants have announced
>   that permitted devices can be used throughout the flight. Certain
>   electronic devices could cause minor interference with aircraft
>   navigational instruments. Therefore, the crew may ask travelers to
>   completely turn off all devices in certain situations. All devices
>   must be turned off and stowed during emergency preparations.
>
> **Travelers may turn on and use cellular service only when the main
>   cabin door is open or when instructed by a flight attendant.** Pagers
>   may be used to receive messages at any time.

For [smoking policies](http://www.no-smoke.org/pdf/smokingpoliciesbusiestairports.pdf):

- Seattle - Not allowed indoors (even e-cigarettes are not allowed)
- San Francisco - Not allowed indoors (even e-cigarettes are not allowed). Smoking permitted 20 feet from the main entrances.
- Denver - there is a smoking lounge at Timberline Steaks & Grill. E-cigarettes are not allowed (even in the smoking lounge).

Comment: Some other planes (including modern Boeing 777-W variants), have USB power. This can be used to charge tablets, etc. The power is either on the arm-rest, or in the seatback